# Empty Screenshots/ Element not found during headless chrome testing

Tags: protractor

I'm quite new to automation testing in general and I'm only starting to pick up the protractor testing framework, so bear with me if the way I'm phrasing some terms doesn't seem right (or leaving out crucial information).

I'm currently trying to write automation testing for an Angular application with the Protractor Framework/ Cucumber Framework. The tests are running fine outside the headless browser mode but they seem to be failing in headless. Throwing the error:

> NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator

I've searched a ton online but I can't seem to find a proper solution
I've tried:

1. Setting the window size as follows:

   ```
   args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1980,1080" ]
   //also tried with --no-sandbox, --start-maximized
   ```
2. Looking at the Angular lifecycle method (if this is even relevant)

   These are my chrome settings:

   ```
   chromeOptions: {
      useAutomationExtension: false,
      args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1980,1080" ]
   }
   ```

1. Screenshots taken are empty (white blank screenshots, when tested in normal mode (i.e. not headless) screenshots show the view of the webpage)
2. NoSuchElementError - expecting to be able to find the element given it works in the non-headless mode.

Comment: Can you attach the actual spec code?

Comment: And extended stack trace